# Using pkgutil.iter_modules with py2app

Tags: python, py2app

In my game, I have a lot of different levels, in the following structure:

```
+ levels/
  - Level1.py
  - Level2.py
  - Level3.py
  - ...
```

Level1.py contains `class Level1`, and all the others likewise.

I could import each of my levels thusly:

```
from levels.Level1 import Level1
```

but since I have a lot of them, and I want to import them all in the same place, I wrote a `load_levels` function that sits in `levels/__init__.py`:

```
def load_levels(game,window):
  levels = {}
  for loader, mod_name, ispkg in pkgutil.iter_modules(path=__path__):
    #import and initialise level
  return levels
```

This works great, until I package the application up using `py2app`. Then `pkgutil.iter_modules` contains nothing, presumably because it cannot run within a zip directory (`__path__` is `['/.../dist/main.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python35.zip/levels']`)

What can I do here? Is there a way to configure `py2app` not to zip the directory, or `pkgutil` to work within the zip file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not that pkgutil isn't working, but that modulegraph doesn't package any of my level files since it can't 'see' them at build time.

To get around this, you can list `levels` as a package in `setup.py`, which will make sure all of its contents are bundled. They will not be compiled, however.

If you want to achieve the same thing and ensure the files are compiled, one way around it is to make sure `__all__` in `__init__.py` contains all the modules:

```
for f in os.listdir(__path__):
  mod = os.path.splitext(f)[0]
  if mod not in ['__init__','__pycache__','level_base']:
    __all__.append(mod)
```

and then add the module to `includes` in `setup.py`.

The only problem now is that this code *won't* work from within the packaged app, since `__path__` is no longer a real dir, so you will want to put it in a `try/except` block.